# Batch Script - Obtain all files with multiple extensions

Tags: batch-file

List all files with multiple extensions into a text file.

Below code works fine :

```
 dir /s/b *.jpg /s *.png > temp.txt
```

But, if pwd is desktop and i need to find all files from a particular user directory and its sub directories (Ex : C:\Users\user_name) and the text file should be created in my pwd i.e Desktop in this case. I tried the below code, but it contains all files existing without considering the extension.

```
dir C:\Users\<user_name>\ /s/b *.jpg /s *.png > temp.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switches for `dir` are "global", so adding a switch several times doesn't change anything.

```
dir /s /b C:\Users\<user_name>\*.jpg C:\Users\<user_name>\*.png >temp.txt
```

or

```
pushd C:\Users\<user_name>\
dir /s /b *.jpg *.png>%userprofile%\desktop\temp.txt
popd
```

or more elegant:

```
( pushd C:\Users\<user_name>\
dir /s /b *.jpg *.png
popd ) >temp.txt
```

if you really want `/b/s` for *.jpg and only `/s` for *.png, you will have to work with two `dir`commands.

**EDIT** for getting the extensions from a simple textfile:

```
pushd C:\Users\<user_name>\
(for /f %%e in (extensions.txt) do (
  dir /s /b *%%e
)) >temp.txt
popd
```

`extensions.txt` should look like this:

```
.jpg
.png
.gif
```

If the textfile looks different, this code has to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. That last code works like a charm. Is there anyway to store the extensions list in a text/excel file, read from that file and search ?

Comment: yes, that's possible. But the code will look very different and depends on how your file is structured. I suggest asking another question for this.

Comment: could you just edit your answer and add in ? the file structure being 1 extension per line...

Comment: if the textfile is that simple, it's quite easy. See my edit.

Comment: Works great,... but why is it also acquiring files from AppData even though that folder is hidden ? any way to bypass `%USERPROFILE%/AppData`

Comment: "hidden" dosen't mean "not there". To bypass, just filter the `dir` command:  `dir /s /b *%%e |find  /i /v "%userprofile%\AppData"`

Answer (score 0):

Though some years late, I'd like to share the script I usually use for this same task. It will receive the directory and a list of extensions (expressed as wildcards: `*.jpg`).

In your case, an example of use would be `this_script.bat . *.jpg *.png > files.txt`

```
@echo off

setlocal

rem %1 Directory to list
rem %2 - %9 extensions

if "%2"=="" (
    echo Usage %0 ^<directory^> ^<extensions separated by space^>
    echo Example: %0 . *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.bmp *.gif
    exit /b 1
)

set EXTENSIONS=%2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

pushd %1

rem List files in base directory
call :list_dir %cd%

rem List subdirectories
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /ad /on /b /s') do (
    call :list_dir %%D
)

popd

exit /b 0

rem Lists all files in a directory that match the extensions
:list_dir
pushd %1
set DIR=%1

for %%S in (%EXTENSIONS%) do (
    echo %DIR%\%%S
)

popd
exit /b 0
```

If you require a list in a variable just change the `echo` in `:list_dir` by the expression you need.